# How to remove next line if next line matching pattern with sed?

Tags: sed

I have issues to remove next line if next line matches pattern.
For example :

```
define service{
host_name               A
notification_period     F
}


define service{
host_name               A
notification_period     metrologie
notification_period     F
}
```

I check pattern metrologie. If next line contains notification_period, i want to delete line notification_period     F.

I tried with command sed '/metrologie/{h;d;};/notification_period/{x;!d;}' $file

but It transforms the string to :

```
define service{
host_name               A

}


define service{
host_name               A
notification_period     metrologie
}
```

I would like this output:

```
define service{
host_name               A
notification_period     F
}


define service{
host_name               A
notification_period     metrologie
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You may use

```
sed '/metrologie/{N;/\n.*notification_period/{s/\n.*//}}' file
```

See the [online `sed` demo](https://ideone.com/qr1rCX).

**Details**

- `/metrologie/` - finds a line with `metrologie` 
  and then

  - `N;` - reads the next line to the pattern space with a newline before it
  - `/\n.*notification_period/` - tries to match the current text in the pattern space with a pattern matching newline, any 0+ chars, `notification_period`
  - `{s/\n.*//}}` - if the above pattern matches, replace the newline and all after it with an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed ':a;/metrologie/{n;/notification_period/d;ba}' file
```

If a line contains `metrologie` print and fetch the next line. If that line contains `notification_period` delete it, otherwise repeat.

Comment: So, the difference with my solution is that all lines below a line with `metrologie` containing `notification_period` are removed, right?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew no, the difference is if a line below `metrologie` does not contain `notification_period`, that line is not forgotten but tested to see if it contains `metrologie` too. In your solution the line is removed if the condition is true, but never tested again if false.